# C# File serialization error

Tags: c#, file, serialization, runtime-error

Good day all

I am trying to teach myself how to do C# file serialization again after not looking at it for year. I seem to have an error in my code, but cannot seem to fix it or grasp the problem. It has to do with deserializing the objects and reading it into an array.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Serializing_Files
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool IsFemale { get; set; }

        public Dog(string Name, string Breed, int Age, bool IsFemale)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Breed = Breed;
            this.Age = Age;
            this.IsFemale = IsFemale;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string dogInfo;

            dogInfo = "Name: "+this.Name;
            return dogInfo;
        }
    }

    public static class DogsFile
    {
        public static BinaryFormatter BFormatter { get; set; }
        public static FileStream FStream { get; set; }
        public static void WriteDog(string FileName, Dog NewDog)
        {
            FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            BFormatter.Serialize(FStream, NewDog);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has been written to the file.", NewDog.Name);
            FStream.Close();
        }

        public static Dog[] ReadDogs(string FileName)
        {
            FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            Dog[] DogArray = new Dog[FStream.Length];
            int i = 0;

            while (FStream.Position < FStream.Length)
            {
                DogArray[i] = (Dog)BFormatter.Deserialize(FStream); //line where error occurs
                Console.WriteLine("The file contans the following Dogs:");
                Console.WriteLine(DogArray[i].ToString());

                i++;
            }
            FStream.Close();
            return DogArray;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Dogfile.ser";
            Dog[] allDogs = new Dog[3];

            allDogs[0] = new Serializing_Files.Dog("Scruffy", "Maltese", 3, true);
            DogsFile.WriteDog(filename, allDogs[0]);

            allDogs[1] = new Serializing_Files.Dog("Butch", "Bulldog", 1, false);
            DogsFile.WriteDog(filename, allDogs[1]);

            allDogs[2] = new Serializing_Files.Dog("Balo", "Chow Chow", 1, false);
            DogsFile.WriteDog(filename, allDogs[2]);

            DogsFile.ReadDogs(filename);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following runtime error in line 60:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The input stream is not a valid binary format.
>   The starting contents (in bytes) are:
>   0B-5F-5F-42-61-63-6B-69-6E-67-46-69-65-6C-64-01-01 ...

I wrote this file using a combination of several tutorials, so I might have misunderstood something. Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? I would be extremely grateful for any advice you might be able to offer.

A follow up question: I am using "FileMode.Append" when adding to the file. How would I make sure that the file exists in the first place? Should I run a line of code at the start using "FileMode.Create" separately, or is there a better practice approach that I could use?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure the code fully compiled.  Go into the bin folder of the project and check the date on the executable in the debug and release folder.  Usually when code run properly on one machine and not on another machine the file in the release folder got compiled and you are running the executable from the debug folder.

Comment: Note that I have since decided that it is better practice to write an array of dogs and to read it as an array instead of doing a loop to write each individually. The "append" command also seems to create the file if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not crash.
Probably you created file with different objects (Maybe you added some properties afterwards) and now it cannot deserialize. Remove your file and launch your program again. File mode works fine. No need to change.

Another point is to serialize collection instead of writing objects one by one.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the error. If I write to a new file, it works perfectly :)

Comment: in scope of his question ,  code doesn't work fine , first what i noticed is new Dog[FStream.Length]; and  while (FStream.Position < FStream.Length). let FStream.Length = 256 , what happen in this case.

Comment: @Z.R.T You are quite right about array. But it does not crash as it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Z.R.T., I was wondering about that myself... But it seems to work?

Comment: @phunder it will allocate lots of memory since it will create dog for each byte. But it will work.

Comment: @Z.R.T. I am trying to write a similar program where the objects are written into the file one at a time (just to see how it works). I'm currently stuck on the error you pointed out earlier, namely "new Dog[FStream.Length]; and while (FStream.Position < FStream.Length). let FStream.Length = 256". Is there a way to determine how many dog objects are in a file?

Comment: @phunder Maybe it's better to use List<Dog>?

Comment: @AccessDenied yes you are correct, I agree. The problem is that I need to show this to a group of students who do not yet know about lists, so I am trying to figure out a way to do it with arrays. Lists are not part of our first year syllabus. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @phunder You can also write header at the begining of the file and update it each time you add record to the end of file.

Comment: @AccessDenied would you possibly be able to point me towards an example of that?

Comment: Binary file is just a chunk of bytes. Just assume that first four bytes would be number of records in the array. Move FileStream to 0 position and writer new number of records.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class DogsFile
{
    public static BinaryFormatter BFormatter { get; set; }
    public static FileStream FStream { get; set; }
    public static void WriteDog(string FileName, Dog[] NewDog)
    {
        FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        BFormatter.Serialize(FStream, NewDog);
        FStream.Close();
    }

    public static Dog[] ReadDogs(string FileName)
    {
        FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var DogArray = (Dog[])BFormatter.Deserialize(FStream);
        FStream.Close();
        return DogArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just did something very similar to this as well

Answer (score 0):

After some helpful suggestions from @Access Denied and @Z.R.T, here is the working code. Thanks guys!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Serializing_Files
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool IsFemale { get; set; }

        public Dog(string Name, string Breed, int Age, bool IsFemale)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Breed = Breed;
            this.Age = Age;
            this.IsFemale = IsFemale;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string dogInfo;

            dogInfo = "Name: " + this.Name + Environment.NewLine + "Breed: " + this.Breed + Environment.NewLine + "Age: " + this.Age + Environment.NewLine;
            if (this.IsFemale)
            {
                dogInfo += "Gender: Female";
            }
            else
            {
                dogInfo += "Gender: Male";
            }
            dogInfo += Environment.NewLine;

            return dogInfo;
        }
    }

    public static class DogsFile
    {
        public static BinaryFormatter BFormatter { get; set; }
        public static FileStream FStream { get; set; }
        public static void WriteDog(string FileName, Dog[] NewDogs)
        {
            FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            BFormatter.Serialize(FStream, NewDogs);

            Console.WriteLine("The following dogs were written to the file:" + Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < NewDogs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(NewDogs[i].ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            FStream.Close();
        }

        public static Dog[] ReadDogs(string FileName)
        {
            FStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var DogArray = (Dog[])BFormatter.Deserialize(FStream);

            Console.WriteLine("The file contains the following dogs:"+Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < DogArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DogArray[i].ToString());
            }

            FStream.Close();
            return DogArray;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Dogfile1.ser";
            Dog[] allDogs = new Dog[3];

            allDogs[0] = new Dog("Scruffy", "Maltese", 3, true);

            allDogs[1] = new Dog("Butch", "Bulldog", 1, false);

            allDogs[2] = new Dog("Balo", "Chow Chow", 1, false);

            DogsFile.WriteDog(filename, allDogs);

            DogsFile.ReadDogs(filename);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```